# Select previous element of a different type in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML in the following format

```
<h3>Atlanta</h3>
<div id="wpbdp-listings-list">
   <span class="no-listings">No listings found.</span>
</div>
<h3>Canton</h3>
<div id="wpbdp-listings-list">
   <span class="no-listings">No listings found.</span>
</div>
<h3>Woodstock</h3>
<div id="wpbdp-listings-list">
   <span class="some-listings">SOME LISTINGS ARE HERE.</span>
</div>
```

For every class that exists "no-listings" I'm trying to find and hide the h3 above it, which is outside of the div.  Is there a way to do this with jQuery?  This h3 may contain different text but will always be in the same place in the HTML.  In the above example the Atlanta and Canton H3's would be hidden but not the Woodstock H3.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. What have you tried? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DOM navigation methods. `parent()` goes up one level, `prev()` goes to the previous element.

```js
$(".some-listings").parent().prev().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Atlanta</h3>
<div id="wpbdp-listings-list">
   <span class="no-listings">No listings found.</span>
</div>
<h3>Canton</h3>
<div id="wpbdp-listings-list">
   <span class="no-listings">No listings found.</span>
</div>
<h3>Woodstock</h3>
<div id="wpbdp-listings-list">
   <span class="some-listings">SOME LISTINGS ARE HERE.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: So the parent() selects the DIV and the PREV selects whatever element is above that.  Perfect!